# Find one object belonging to other connecting with relation

Tags: java, rest, h2

i have some problem and no idea how to resolve it. I have springboot Restfull webservice conected with H2 db, where i have Teams and Persons. Both entions are connected with many2many realtion(one person can be in many team and one team can have many person). Now i want to create method where i should return a list of persons belonging to the teams. 
This is my method where i add People to team. This method is created in team service class:

```
@Transactional
public boolean addPersonsToTeams(Long teamId, Long personId) {

    Assert.notNull(personId, "Object can't be null!");
    Assert.notNull(teamId, "Object can't be null!");

    try {
        Person person = personRepository.getOne(personId);
        Team team = teamRepository.getOne(teamId);
        team.getPersons().add(person);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CreateEntityException(e);
    }

    return true;
}
```

So should i create my new method in person service? How to create method where i should return list with connected persons and teams from database?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code I get to know the Team has persons relationship. In this case you should create method in Team Service class for both adding person to the team or fetching persons from the team.

One more thing you should create DAO Layer for interacting with Repositories rather to tightly coupled in service layer.

Comment: I have dao i use model mapper. But i have problem. I need to return list with two objects but this is imposible

Comment: Ok. Why you should wrap both the lists into one custom instance type and pass to modelmapper to convert.

Comment: Both lists? I don't have a list

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I was thinking different, what do you mean return list with two objects?

Comment: I have two entity - persons and teams with relation. Now I want to create a method which return only this persons who have teams. Because in my project I can have a persons who is not assigned to team. I want to return this persons with teams in list form.

Comment: You should declared a method in person repository findAllByTeamNotNull